# Union of subspaces is a subset of the sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I'm new to proofs and have a proof I'm trying to figure out, but I don't think I'm correct:

Given subspaces $W_1 ... W_n \subset{V}$ where V is a vector space, and letting:

$$W_1 + ... + W_n = \{w_1 + ... + w_n | w_i \in{W_i}, i = 1, ... , n\}$$

Prove that $W_1 \cup ... \cup W_n \subset\{W_1 + ... + W_n\}$.

My attempt:

Proof.

Let $w_i \in{W_i}$ for $i = 1, ..., n$, then:

$$w_1 \in{W_1} AND ... AND w_n \in{W_n}$$

$$\implies w_i \in{W_1 \cup ... \cup W_n}$$

Furthermore, since $W_1 + ... + W_n$ is subspace,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \in{W_1 + ... + W_n}$$

$$w_1 + ... + w_n \in{W_1 + ... + W_n}$$

Therefore,

$$W_1 \cup ... \cup W_n \subset\{W_1 + ... + W_n\}$$

QED.

Note: The proof that the sum of subspaces is indeed a subspace need not be shown here as it has already been shown before.

Is this proof correct? If not - or even if so - any assistance or improvements are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is wrong: a vector is in the union of the subspaces if and only if is in at least one of them. Here is a proof:

> *Proof*. Take $v \in W_1 \cup \cdots \cup W_n$. Then there is an index $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $v \in W_j$. It follows that $$v = \underbrace{0 + \cdots + v + \cdots + 0}_{\small \textrm{the $v$ is in the $j$-th place}} \in W_1 + \cdots + W_j + \cdots + W_n. \ \blacksquare$$

Comment: So if we had each $w_i \in{W_i}$, wouldn't that imply that $w_i$ is in the union. Or am I misunderstanding what you're saying? Also, what does your proof show?

Comment: Yes, $w_i \in W_i$ implies that $w_i \in W_1 \cup \cdots \cup W_n$, but, you should prove that every vector in $W_1 \cup \cdots \cup W_n$ is also in $W_1 + \cdots + W_n$. So, your proof doesn't show anything relevant.

Comment: Oh I see. So then the proof you gave would show that for any and every vector in the union, the sum of that vector and the 0s would be an element of the sum of the subspaces. Thanks for the response!